# How to reduce the error of CNN imagine classification model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I have to build a CNN model that classifies images. The images are pieces of spectrograms of songs (3 seconds) and the model has to identify its music genre. The dataset is composed of 10 categories, each one with 1000 elements.

I don't have experience with neural networks and ony reading documents in the internet i've built the model, but it seems it has problem while training (error is oscillating a lot). Below there's the graph of 30 ephocs training (consider it's written "validation" instead of "test" in the legend) and the relative code.

How can i improve this model? Also the training is so slowly, it can be improved?

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 3)

model = keras.Sequential()
# 1st conv layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(
    32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
    (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

# 2nd conv layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
    (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

# 3rd conv layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
    (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

# flatten output and feed it into dense layer
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

# output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
                  from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=30
)
```

Comment: The training loss is going down so I dont see a big problem just train for longer and stop when the validation loss is significantly more than training loss

Comment: You really don't need `from_logits = True` as you already have `softmax` in the last dense.